# How to clone a class instance and change just one field in Objective C or Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, immutability

Scala provides a way to change just one property when copying an immutable object. Does Objective C or Swift for that matter have a equivalent or is there any library that adds similar functionality?

- https://coderwall.com/p/8wofhq/update-property-value-of-immutable-object-while-maintaining-immutability

NOTE: This question is about only referencing a single property not about updating an array of objects.

Comment: No, neither Obj-C, Swift, C++ or Java has such an operation in their grammar. They don't even have the concept of immutability so such an operation doesn't really make sense in them.

Comment: It would be ideal if you'd pick one language or the other; if you truly don't care, then you're really asking about Cocoa (Touch), and should retag.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Fair enough. Will do next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in, but it's easy enough to write a method that does this, using KVC to set the value:

```
@implementation NSObject (WSSCopyMutating)

- (instancetype)WSSCopyChangingValue:(id)val forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    id newObj = [self copy];
    [newObj setValue:val forKey:key];

    return newObj;
}

@end
```

This requires that the class you're copying conforms to `NSCopying`. `setValue:forKey:` will find the field you've named regardless of its public visibility or writeability.

Comment: Thanks I found more info about this from @bbum in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502708/why-does-a-readonly-property-still-allow-writing-with-kvc